# NSPredicate for an Array of NSDictionary keys

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = @{ @"1":@"Egg Benedict",
                                @"2":@"Mushroom Risotto",
                                @"3":@"Full Breakfast",
                                @"4":@"Hamburger",
                                @"5":@"Ham and Egg Sandwich",
                                @"6":@"Cream Brelee"};
NSMutableArray *myKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myDictionary allKeys]];
```

I want to filter myDictionary with a predicate. How should I structure it?
As an algorithm I guess it should be something like this:

```
[filteredKeys removeAllObjects];
for (NSString *a in myKeys) {
    if ([[myDictionary objectForKey:a] rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound) {
        [filteredKeys addObject:a];
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that with a predicate string?

Answer (score 0):

You have `myObjects` as a mutable array of keys, so you can filter that array. The keys are just strings. The predicate for that should be:

```
@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText
```

once you have filtered the array you can get your updated dictionary with:

```
NSDictionary *filtered = [myDictionary dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:myObjects];
```